# Phase to phase voltage noise in a BLDC sine wave controller

Tags: stm32, pwm, embedded, brushless-dc-motor, sine

I am trying to program a BLDC controller using SVPWM. The waveform attained from phase is almost what I excepted. I also cross verified with another BLDC controller which is available in market. The phase to phase waveform from my controller is noisy when compared to another controller. Can anyone help me to solve these issues?

Phase to phase waveform from my controller:

[image]
[image]

Phase to phase waveform from another controller:

[image]

Comment: It looks like the existing controller may be using a trapezoidal waveform. You should run the signals through a simple RC low pass filter to observe the effective waveform as seen by the motor, due to its inductance.

Comment: Surendran - Hi, In your previous related questions [here](/q/638876) & [here](/q/641895), other site members asked clarification questions in comments. You did not reply with the requested information & have not updated the questions. Now you are asking yet another question. Does that mean you have abandoned the previous ones? If so, you risk wasting the time of other people, who may see your still-open previous questions and try to help you there. So please (a) Only ask questions if you are prepared to clarify them & supply reasonable additional info, when requested. (b) Reply to comments. TY

Comment: @PStechPaul  The existing controller is also a SVPWM waveform. i will also attach image with applied low pass filter for that.

Comment: @SamGibson Iam sorry.

Comment: @Surendran - Hi, I see you deleted [one](/q/638876) of your previous questions (which had no answers) but you can't delete [the other](/q/641895) one, as it has multiple answers. For *that* question, you have 2 choices: (a) If any of the answers solved your question, it would be appropriate to [accept that answer](/help/someone-answers) so that future readers can clearly see what the solution was. (b) If none of the answers solves your problem & you don't want to continue with the question, please edit that question to explain you won't be continuing (so people can see you don't want help).

Comment: @SamGibson Hi, the post which i have deleted , that issues has been solved and i don't known how to close that post so i have deleted and another one issues is not solved

Comment: @Surendran - Hi, Re; "*the post which i have deleted , that issues has been solved and i don't known how to close that post so i have deleted*" Although Stack Exchange usually allows unanswered Q to be deleted, it looks strange / bad to delete a Q on topic X, then to ask more Q about topic X. Perhaps there was useful info in the *earlier* Q (or its comments) which would help readers to understand the *later* Q. In general, if you solve your own Q it is better to write your own A (and, if it is the only A, you can accept your own A to close that Q). If other Q is unsolved, is is abandoned?

Comment: @SamGibson Thank you Know I understand how to close the question which i have post. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues has been solved. I have changed the calculation method so that Phase to Phase noise is been reduced.

Comment: People would be delighted to know in detail what the solution was